# What exactly is happening when I copy and then edit this list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I cannot figure out at all why this is happening:

```
A = [[1,0], [2,2]]
B = list(A)

print('start A:', A, 'start B:', B)
A[0][0] = 999
print('end A:', A, 'end B:', B)
```

This returns:

```
start A: [[1, 0], [2, 2]] start B: [[1, 0], [2, 2]]
end A: [[999, 0], [2, 2]] end B: [[999, 0], [2, 2]]
```

The lists A and B end up being the same, even though I explicitly copied B from A. This only happens when I do something like A[0][0] = 999; if I replace that with A[0] = 999 then A and B are different at the end.

What's the reason behind this, and is there any way to change A in this manner without affecting B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a *shallow copy* of the original list, that is a new list containing new references to the same objects as the original list.

Modifying the new list object does not alter the original list.  Modifying the objects in the new list *does* modify the objects in the old list because they are the same.

To get a completely separate list, use [`copy.deepcopy()`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to create a *deep copy*.

Answer (score 2):

Both A and B contain the same two lists.

Your code is roughly equivalent to this:

```
x = [1, 0]
y = [2, 2]

A = [x, y]
B = [x, y]
```

The operation `A[0][0] = 999` is effectively just doing `x[0] = 999`. That is, it doesn't modify A itself, it modifies the first element of the list `x`. Since both A and B have references to `x`, both will see the change.

Answer (score 1):

A simple copy operation like you did is *shallow*, it only copies the items one level deep and does not recurse into nested structures. You need

```
>>> import copy
>>> A = [[1,0], [2,2]]
>>> B = copy.deepcopy(A)
>>> print('start A:', A, 'start B:', B)
start A: [[1, 0], [2, 2]] start B: [[1, 0], [2, 2]]
>>> A[0][0] = 999
>>> print('end A:', A, 'end B:', B)
end A: [[999, 0], [2, 2]] end B: [[1, 0], [2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>`A` and `B` are two different names for the same chunk of memory within your computer.</strike>

`A` and `B` are two separate list objects, but `A[0]` and `B[0]` are two different names for the same chunk of memory within your computer.  Try the following from the interpreter:

```
id(B)
id(A)
id(B[0])
id(A[0])
```

Comment: No, they aren't.  They are separate list objects.

Answer (score 1):

Python code manipulates *references* to *objects*.

Assigning to a variable is just binding a name to refer to an object.

A list consists of a bunch of references to objects. `list(A)` finds all the objects referenced in `A` and makes a new list with references to all the same objects. So if `A` is a list of lists, `list(A)` makes a new list with references to the same lists that were in `A`. So changing any of the sub-lists will be visible from both `A` and the new list.

`copy.deepcopy` exists to help you get around this, when you need a full "deep" copy of something.

Once you learn to think about Python code as manipulating references to objects like this, you will intuitively understand when code is likely to end up referring to the same object from multiple places like this, though there will probably always be obscure cases that surprise you.